# Not able to update digital clock

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have to display respective time zone in digital format. The clock is displayed but it only updates after refreshing the page. Below is the code I used.
Below is my javascript code:

```
time: function() {
    var zone = _.date.fleetTimeZone();
    return moment().zone(zone).format('h:mm:ss a');
}.property('DS.session.last_fleet_interacted'),
```

Below is my handlebars:

```
<div class="time">{{time}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn `time` into a property, and update it each second, using `setTimeout()` or something. Then it'll work because of data binding (I assume Ember.js because tags).

Alternatively, just do a `setTimeout()` and re-render the time manually.